# Is there an environment tag helper equivalent for CSS files?

Tags: razor-pages

In my Razor views I can add the following conditional tags:

```
                <environment include="Development">
                    <a href="dev-url">DEV URL</a>
                </environment>
                <environment exclude="Development">
                    <a href="prod-url">PROD URL</a>
                </environment>
```

I want to be able to do the same in my CSS files - is this possible? If not this would be a very convenient feature.

Comment: Tag helpers don't work in CSS files, because they are not processed by the Razor engine. CSS doesn't provide anything that enables you to conditionally apply styles based on the context in which the code is running.

Comment: To echo the previous comment there's no tag helpers in the CSS file. You can link to separate CSS files or use CSS class names that are different and conditionally use them